Nuget package generation: an alternative to <files> inside a project file
I have a bit of a non-standard project which I would like to distribute as a nuget package. I'll need to explicitly specify files included in the package, excluding everything else.
At the moment inside my .nuspec file I have  section which allows to include only what's needed:
<files>
    <file src="myfile.xxx" target="content" />
</files>

This way only myfile.xxx is packed, nothing else, and that's what's needed.
But I have to include a reference to it in a project file together with some other package-related properties:
<PropertyGroup>
    <PackageOutputPath>bin\Package</PackageOutputPath>
    <NuspecFile>myspec.nuspec</NuspecFile>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
</PropertyGroup>

It would be more convenient to include all properties inside the project file itself. But I can't find an alternative to <files> section of .nuspec.
Anyone knows about it?
